# Break down picture in reactangles

Tags: image, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm.
I want to draw a image (2d-array of pixels) with the lowest number of rectangles . It's possible to overwrite already drawed areas  by a new rectangles. 
In the first step I  convert every pixel of the picture to a quad with the size 1x1 and a color.  Than I want to reduce the number of objects by creating bigger rectangles. 
In the end I want an array of rectangles. When I iterate over it and draw it on the pane, I want to have the original picture.
Is there any algorithm?
The runtime doesn't matter.

Example1:

|.bl.|.bl.|.bl.|-----|.bl...........|

|.bl.|.gr.|.bl.| -> |...............| + |.gr.|

|.bl.|.bl.|.bl.|-----|..............|

bl = black, gr = green

Example2:

|....|....|.bl.|

|.bl.|.bl.|.bl.| --> |.bl.|.bl.|.bl.| + |.bl.|

|.bl.|.bl.|.bl.|-----|.bl.|.bl.|.bl.|

Comment: Do you finally aim at some sort of vectorization or compression? Please give an example of the problem and the desired representation.

Comment: "The runtime doesn't matter." Then try every possible combinations of rectangles of any size until you've found the right one. :-P

Comment: ok, I added an example :), i hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for Quad Tree Compression :)

http://www.gitta.info/DataCompress/en/html/rastercomp_chain.html